# Java change the position of integers in an array

Tags: java, arrays, oop, netbeans

I have to introduce 10 integers in an array. For example int A[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}. Then I have to print the array in normal order which is fine, and after I have to make each element of the array hop over to the next position and the last element to the first position. Assuming we have the same integers in the array as before the result would be this: A[] = {10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

Here's my code so far but I get the out of bounds error. Also I don't know how to flip the last element to the first position

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int A[] = new int[10];

    System.out.println("Introduce the array numbers");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        A[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    //array in normal order
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.print("["+A[i]+"]");
    }
    //here i have to print the modified array
    System.out.println("");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.print("["+A[i+1]+"]");
    }
}
```

Comment: Printing the modified array is exactly the same code as printing the initial array. What you're missing, is the code to actually *modify* the array, i.e. store the last value is a temporary variable, copy all the other values 1 position to the right, the put the stored "last " value into first position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, the goal is to start with this array:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

And to modify it such that you wind up with this:

```
[10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

What you are doing here, in essence, is pushing every number one spot to the right. The right-most number, when "pushed one spot to the right", will wrap around to the start of the array.

If we start by just taking the first number and copying it to the right, we run into a problem. The start of the array `[1, 2]` is now `[1, 1]`... which means we no longer know what number to push forward into the third slot. In other words, if we just blindly started at the beginning of the array and pushed numbers to the right, we'd wind up with this:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

The best way to solve this issue is to do our work *starting at the end of the array*, and then to work backwards. So first we push the `9` over to the right, then the `8`, and so on.

Once we do that, the only problem is what we do with the first position. If we just moved everything over by one, we'd have this:

```
[???, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

To make matters worse, we might actually crash the program by trying to acces the "negative one-th" element to move it over to the zero index.

The best way around *this* is to break our problem up into three steps:

- Save the last number in the array for later
- For each position, starting from the end and working back to the second position, set the number to be equal to the number at the position before it
- Set the first number in the array to the saved "last" number

Here's what that looks like in code:

```
int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

int last = numbers[numbers.length - 1]; // last now stores 10

// for index 9 to index 1, copy numbers to the right
for (int i = numbers.length - 1; i > 0; --i) {
    numbers[i] = numbers[i - 1];
}

numbers[0] = last; // the first number is now 10
```